# How to identify each of every elements is Before from next element in a List

Tags: scala

I have a list that contain number of elements which are formatted as Local Date Time type as follow.

```
List(2017-06-25T00:00, 2017-06-25T00:05:13, 2017-06-25T00:11:11, 2017-06-25T00:17:39, 2017-06-25T00:24:44, 2017-06-25T00:32:33, 2017-06-25T00:41:11, 2017-06-25T01:01:03)
```

I want to check each and every elements of List is before from next element.As example first value of list is before from second value in list. Like wise I want to check for whole elements inside list.Can any one help me.

Comment: What do you mean by "whole elements"?

Comment: I want to check each of every elements of list with date in the sequence is earlier than next one

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will test if a `List` of well-formatted date strings are all in chronological order.

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime

val dates: List[String] = List( "2017-06-25T00:00"
                              , "2017-06-25T00:05:13"
                                // etc.
                              , "2017-06-25T01:01:03"
                              )

dates.iterator
     .map(LocalDateTime.parse)
     .sliding(2)
     .forall(x => x(0) isBefore x(1))  // returns true/false
```

The `.iterator` is included so that the date-strings can be parsed lazily, i.e. if one of the first dates is out of order, then the subsequent dates in the list don't have to be parsed at all.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a method for checking that each string with a date in the sequence is earlier than the next (it assumes that you have a method called `isBefore` that compares two of these Strings

```
@tailrec
def isMonotouslyIncreasing(seq: Seq[String]): Boolean = {
  if(seq.size <= 1) true
  else if(isBefore(seq(0), seq(1))) isMonotouslyIncreasing(seq.tail)
  else false
}
```

Comment: This is not very efficient. `seq.drop(1)` is `O(n)` in general case, so your solution is `O(n²)`.

Comment: Here you have pass String type sequence of data. But my requirement for LocalDateTime type of data

Comment: @Aivean I changed `drop(1)` to `tail` (which is `O(1)`) making the total runtime complexity `O(N)`

Comment: @DinushaDilanka Then all you need to do is use `LocalDateTime.isBefore` instead of the `isBefore(a: String, b: String): Boolean` that's used in the example